# How to dynamically filter in a range in excel?

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula

I have this filter shown below.  It currently filters data from sheetnames from A5, A6, and A7.

How can I change this filter to be dynamic? So if I were to add a value to A8 it would automatically be added to the filter?

=LET(
xml_queries,
TEXTJOIN("", TRUE,
IF((INDIRECT("'" & A5 & "-Fields'!H6:H206")="InProgress") + (INDIRECT("'" & A5 & "-Fields'!H6:H206")="Incomplete") + (INDIRECT("'" & A5 & "-Fields'!H6:H206")="Problem"),
INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & A5 & "-Fields'!A6:A206"), , ),
""),
IF((INDIRECT("'" & A6 & "-Fields'!H6:H206")="InProgress") + (INDIRECT("'" & A6 & "-Fields'!H6:H206")="Incomplete") + (INDIRECT("'" & A6 & "-Fields'!H6:H206")="Problem"),
INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & A6 & "-Fields'!A6:A206"), , ),
""),
IF((INDIRECT("'" & A7 & "-Fields'!H6:H206")="InProgress") + (INDIRECT("'" & A7 & "-Fields'!H6:H206")="Incomplete") + (INDIRECT("'" & A7 & "-Fields'!H6:H206")="Problem"),
INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & A7 & "-Fields'!A6:A206"), , ),
"")
),
FILTERXML("" & xml_queries & "", "//a")
)

Comment: Can you present a screenshot, and/or link to a read-only test Excel spreadsheet which we can clone? It's much easier to prepare a working answer if we don't have to reconstruct the exact shape of your data.